# Extracting individual components of a vector in the Source Shader Editor

Tags: shaders, hlsl, source-engine

I'm using the Source Shader editor and would like to mask a vector output to one or two values, yet there is no existing mask node, as far as I can see.

What HLSL code should I use to output what I need? The input would be in the format "x y z". Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "mask" in this context? We use that term to mean a few different things, even just within graphics contexts, so a little extra description can help make sure you get accurate, useful answers.

Comment: @DMGregory I mean mask in the sense that - say I had a vector with the value 1.01 5.00 3.56, and representing these 3 values are X Y Z respectively - I'm looking to be able to split this into 3 seperate variables. The C++ equivalent of it would be something similar to
*#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    str x, y, z;
    cin >> x >> y >> z;
    return 0;
}*
if that helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the Swizzle node. According to [Valve's documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SourceShaderEditor/Ref_nodes_HLSL):

> **Swizzle** (Vectors)
>
> Uses arbitrary [swizzling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swizzling_(computer_graphics)) on a vector. You can also swizzle with constants and change the vector dimensions as you see fit. Use the properties dialog to define the swizzle operation, supports [token channels](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SourceShaderEditor/Ref_vocabulary#Token_channels).

So to take an input vector (x, y, z) and select just the y component, you'd place a Swizzle node by right-clicking and selecting `New node -> Math (Vectors) -> Swizzle`, then double-click it to access its properties and enter the string "y" to output just the y component as its own pin.

You can add additional Swizzle nodes to split out the x and z components too, to have three separate paths in your graph for the three components of the vector.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the swizzle node allowed you to do that - huge thanks

Answer (score -3):

try using a float3 since that is the way to get x y z into a shader

Comment: Can you explain how you'd apply this to "mask a vector output to one or two values" in the Source shader editor?

Comment: idk, you want to get 1-2 outputs from 3 inputs? sounds like you want clamp or get rid of an axis.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88110/2d-hlsl-world-position?rq=1

Comment: If you don't know, then it might be a bit premature to post an answer. Sometimes it's best to wait for the asker to clarify what they need, to ensure our answers are on-target and useful to them.